# Oracle SQL Query to count data occurance, count by day and by weeks between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking for a query which can give me count of data in a matrix format for count of data between dates and some additional criteria 
this is how I want to see the data output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJAkF.jpg)

Comment: coding service ?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do if I were you is create an embedded select that enumerates your date objects into your months 
ex.

```
CASE WHEN myDate between Date1 and Date2 THEN '1 week prior'

CASE WHEN myDate between Date3 and Date4 THEN '2 weeks prior'
```

etc. etc.

Then in your top level select statement you can use a group by method on that enumerated value and the count() function.

This is the best I can do without seeing any actual tables/code